# ul Component Won't Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I've done a simple menu using some HTML, CSS and Javascript. The main idea is that it should be hided until the user click on it, but the problem is that it won't start the page hidden and nothing happens when I click, just like if the Javascript won't active. Here is part of my files:

**index.html**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/sample.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <center>
            <div class="leftMenu" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</div>
            <a href="./"><h1>Test</h1></a>
        </center>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://developmentcloud.blogspot.com/">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**menu.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header ul').addClass('hide');
    $('#header').append('<div class="leftMenu" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</div>');
});

function toggleClass() {
    $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide');
    $('#header .leftMenu').toggleClass('pressed');
}
```

**sample.css**

```
#header ul.hide {
    display: none;
}

#header div.pressed {
    -webkit-border-image: url(graphics/button_clicked.png) 0 8 0 8;
}
```

What I'm making wrong and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at least part of the problem is that the menu toggle div you're creating is using the function `toggleMenu()` and not `toggleClass()`.

**EDIT**: I made a jsfiddle that shows the changes I would propose to make it work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/avidal/dDDKz/

The key is to remove the onclick attributes, and use jQuery to handle the event binding for all current, and future matching elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header ul').addClass('hide');
    $('#header').append('<div class="leftMenu">Menu</div>');

    $('#header div.leftMenu').live('click', toggleClass);
});

function toggleClass() {
    $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide');
    $('#header .leftMenu').toggleClass('pressed');
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed when I modified the code [2], but I prefer it using the `onclick` event, so the things get more organized on my code(that is already very big)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a few things:

1. Make sure you have a doctype.  You said this was just part of your code, so perhaps you do, but just to be sure, I'll point this out anyway.  You can just use the html5 doctype (it is compatible with IE6 if that's a worry):

   <!DOCTYPE html>

       <html>

       <head>...head stuff here </head>

       <body> ...Body stuff here</body>

       </html>
2. Make sure you are loading the jquery library.  Again, maybe you already are, but just making sure your bases are covered here.  I'd suggest putting it in your HEAD. You should also move menu.js out of the head and just below the closing BODY tag.
3. If you want the UL to start off hidden, you should have the default CSS for it display none.  Otherwise, even if your script was working, you would see the ul for a moment before it became hidden as the page would first load and then the JS would apply the class. In that gap between page loading and JS applying your class, the UL will be visible.
4. Your scripts could really be optimized, and I apologize for not being more specific (shouldn't write these when I'm trying to get ready for bed), but I'll at least point out the most obvious fix here - make sure that you are calling the correct method.  I see that in the HTML snippet you are appending, you are calling toggleMenu(), but in your actual JS, your function is called toggleClass.  Change one of those so they match.